# Is there any way to prompt MessageBox when user press browser back or next button in React

Tags: reactjs

I written something like this but i am sure its incorrect.

```
window.onpopstate = (e) => {
  MessageBox.showConfirmMessage('You clicked back or foward button. Go and lose changes?').then(result => {
    if (!result.confirm) {
      window.history.pushState(null, null, window.location.pathname);
     }
   });
}
```

Comment: Huan, does my answer help you?

Comment: It only work on refresh button for me. Is there any way to prompt a Message box that are imported?

Comment: what do you mean refresh? if you implement it and then hit back, alert pops up, no?

Comment: Ya, if i hit back or next, no alert pops up. Only reload button triggers it.

Comment: did you implement my code below?

Comment: Yup, maybe i implement it incorrectly. I wanted to implement it if a dialog is opened.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried this (for both)?

```
window.onbeforeunload = function () {
    return 'Are you sure you want to go leave page?';
};
```